# htaccess rewrite using wildcard and multiple subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, wildcard, subdomain

I want to implement a TEST, CERT and PROD webpages on one single webhosting using a single domain. 
The websites is using wildcards for the first subdomain.

I have the following code:

```
# for TEST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).test.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory3
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory3/$1 [L]

# for CERT
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).cert.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory2/$1 [L]

# for PROD
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory1/$1 [L]
```

This has 3 problems:
**1)** The URL is changed in the browser adress bar so the user can see the new URL.
I would like the user the see the original types URL
Showing:

```
http:\\subdomain1.cert.com\directory2
```

instead of:

```
http:\\subdomain1.cert.com
```

**2)** The TEST and CERT Rewrite is having a `Internal Server Error`. 
It works fine when I replace the wildcard for an fixed subdomain

**3)** The PROD RweriteCond is always valid (also for the CERT and TEST sub. This means that it is always forwarded to directory1

Answer (score 1):

The rules are interferring with each other. Because the host: `(.*).domain.com` also matches the cert and test hosts. You need to exclude them in your "PROD" rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !test.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !cert.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory1/$1 [L]
```

This solves #2 and #3. As for getting redirected, that's something else, These rules won't redirect the browser unless there's an `http://` in the target or a `R` flag in the square brackets.